# Workload on Mysql or PHP+SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a system with different tables: one that stores the tickets, one that stores the departments and another one that stores the users.
The first two tables keep only the static information of the others(basically the id), but when I retrieve the list of the tickets I need also to collect the name of the departments and operators, at this moment I run another query that retrieve the name of the departments and stores them inside a $_SESSION and after it loops thorught it:
Rettrive the the departments' name:

```
 function retrive_depa_names($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName, $SupportDepaTable){
    if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status']<3){
        $mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
        $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
        if($stmt){
            $query = "SELECT `id`,`department_name` FROM ".$SupportDepaTable;
            $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
            if($prepared){
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro, $mustang);
                    if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                        $_SESSION['departments']=array();
                        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                            $_SESSION['departments'][$camaro]=$mustang;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

Extract the Departments' name:

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    /*Departments Name*/
    if(isset($_SESSION['departments'][$depid]))
        $depname=$_SESSION['departments'][$depid];
    else{
        retrive_depa_names($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName, $SupportDepaTable);
        if(isset($_SESSION['departments'][$depid]))
            $depname=$_SESSION['departments'][$depid];
        else
            $depname='Unknown';
     }
    [..]
}
```

The same thing happens with the operators.
I wonder if this is a good way or it's better to give all the work to the query(the one that retrieves the ticket list) using JOIN, because with the method I use the first load is heavy, but after it it should be easier, the problem is that it doesn't keep track of the changes that other users can do.
Basically I would like to know what's the method that could avoid an heavy usage of the server resources.
Thanks

**EDIT**
These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_list_tickets` (
`id`                BIGINT(15)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`enc_id`            CHAR(87),
`ref_id`            VARCHAR(18),
`department_id`     BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`operator_id`       BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`user_id`           BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`title`             VARCHAR(255)                NOT NULL,
`priority`          INT(2)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
`website`           VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
`contype`           ENUM('0','1','2','3','4','5')   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
`ftp_user`          VARCHAR(60)                 NOT NULL,
`ftp_password`      VARCHAR(60)                 NOT NULL,
`created_time`      DATETIME                    NOT NULL,
`last_reply`        DATETIME                    NOT NULL,
`ticket_status`     ENUM('0','1','2','3')       NOT NULL    DEFAULT '2',
`operator_rate`     DECIMAL(4,2)                UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`user_id`,`title`),
INDEX (`enc_id`,`department_id`,`operator_id`,`user_id`,`ticket_status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_departments` (
`id`                BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`department_name`   VARCHAR(70)             NOT NULL,
`active`            ENUM('0','1')           NOT NULL    DEFAULT '1',
`public_view`       ENUM('0','1')           NOT NULL    DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY     (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY      (`department_name`),
INDEX (`id`,`department_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_users` (
`id`                BIGINT(15)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name`              VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`mail`              VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`password`          VARCHAR(200)                    NOT NULL,
`reg_key`           VARCHAR(260)                    ,
`tmp_password`      VARCHAR(87)                     ,
`ip_address`        VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`status`            ENUM('0','1','2','3','4')       NOT NULL    DEFAULT '3',
`holiday`           ENUM('0','1')                   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
`mail_alert`        ENUM('no','yes')                NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'yes',
`assigned_tickets`  INT(5)          UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`solved_tickets`    BIGINT(11)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`number_rating`     BIGINT(6)       UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`rating`            DECIMAL(4,2)    UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`mail`),
INDEX (`name`,`mail`,`status`,`holiday`,`assigned_tickets`,`solved_tickets`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55;
```

**ADDIONATL INFORMATION**
This is the main query to retrieve the tickects list:

```
$query = "SELECT `user_id`,`enc_id`,`department_id`,`operator_id`,`title`,CASE priority WHEN '0' THEN 'Low' WHEN '1' THEN 'Medium' WHEN '2' THEN 'High' WHEN '3' THEN 'Urgent' WHEN '4' THEN 'Critical' ELSE priority  END,`created_time`,`last_reply`,CASE `ticket_status` WHEN '0' THEN '<span class=\'label label-success\'>Closed</span>' WHEN '1' THEN '<span class=\'label label-important\'>Open</span>' WHEN '2' THEN '<span class=\'label label-warning\'>To Assign</span>' WHEN '3' THEN '<span class=\'label label-important\'>Reported</span>' ELSE 'Error' END  FROM ".$SupportTicketsTable." ORDER BY `last_reply` DESC LIMIT 350";
```

Where: `department_id` is the `id` of the department table, `user_id` and `operator_id` are the `id` of the user table (`operator_id` can have `status` equal to `1` or `2`)

Comment: Personally I would use JOINs. Less storage requirements and keeps up to date.

Comment: you should post table schema so that other can help with query.

Comment: @Kickstart what about the resources and the loading time? Because the sessions experies in 30 minutes and dumped as soon as possible

Comment: @Dheed can you tell relation between tables(i.e common column) ?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Sure, just added, hope it's what you are asking for

Comment: If the tables are decently indexed and the queries well designed the joins will be very fast (and you appear to need to join on the primary keys so shouldn't be a problem there). While the session might be dumped after 30 mins of not being used, potentially it could be many hours before the session is unused, during which time the data in the session is getting further out of date. Further you need to store that session data for each user (although you could pull tricks to share that data between users, storing it in a way that can be shared between users, such as a file)